# .map values from a Google Sheets Row

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This code works well for me to build an HTML drop down of a column in Sheets.

```js
function makeMeetingSelection(){
  
  
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet10");
   var Avals = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
   var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
   var length = Alast
   var list = sheet.getRange(2, 1, length, 1).getValues();    
   var rangeStartEnd = list.map(function(r){return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');
  
  
   return rangeStartEnd;
}
```

I have tried to translate it to do the same thing but for a row.

This code doesn't seem to work. It displays the first value of cell `A1`, and then nothing else. What do I need to adjust?

```js
function getTags() {

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
   var Avals = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues();
   var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
   var length = Alast
   var list = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, length).getValues();    
   var rangeStartEnd = list.map(function(r){return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');
   
   return rangeStartEnd
   }
```

Comment: You need to define the sheetName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Improved Solution:

```
 function getTags() {
   const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
   const list = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues().flat();  
   return list.map(r=>'<option>' + r + '</option>').join('');
   }
```

---

### Issues / Improvements:

**1st Issue:**

`var Avals = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues();`

`Avals` is a 2D array with only **one** row.

Therefore, here

`var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;`

`Alast` will be `1` which is not what you want.

---

**2nd Issue:**

`list` is again a 2D array of one row. As a result, using `r[0]` you simply getting only the first row. However, your goal is to iterate every column element. Therefore, you can flatten `list` and then simply consider every element `r`.

---

**Improvements:**

In this solution I made the following improvements:

These lines of codes:

```
   var Avals = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues();
   var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
   var length = Alast
   var list = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, length).getValues();
```

are simply identical to this:

```
const list = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues().flat();
```

I converted the old callback function to an arrow function to make your code look cleaner and more maintainable:

```
const rangeStartEnd = list.map(r=>'<option>' + r + '</option>').join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function getTags() {
   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sheet= ss.getActiveSheet()
   var list = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
   return list.map(function(e){return '<option>' + e + '</option>'; }).join('');
}
```